# Logic errors with search

Tags: c++

I finished my code recently, but my output for my bubbleSort function is wrong.
I missed the first two elements.

I've tried to change it around a bit, but still no success.

NUM_FOR_CAL1

NUM_FOR_CAL2

Seem to be my problems.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this logic error?

```
 //Searching Benchmarks exercise
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//module prototypes
int binarySearch(int t, int arr[], int n);
int bubbleSort(int num[], int n);
void printArray(int arr[], int SIZE);


//global constants
const int SIZE=20;
const int NUM_FOR_CAL1=1;
const int NUM_FOR_CAL2=2;
const int ZERO_FOR_CAL=0;

int main()
{
    //some variables
   int swap;
   int arr[SIZE] = {26, 45, 56, 12, 78, 74, 39, 22, 5, 90, 87, 32, 28, 11, 93, 62, 79, 53, 22, 51};

   //Showing original order, bubble sort, and the number of swaps
   cout << "Original Order : ";
   printArray(arr, SIZE);
   swap = bubbleSort(arr, SIZE);
   cout << "Bubble Sorted : ";
   printArray(arr, SIZE);
   cout << "Number of location swaps: " << swap << endl;
   int num, pos, total = ZERO_FOR_CAL;
   char YesNo;
   do
   {
      cout << "Select a number in the Array to search for: ";
      cin >> num;
      pos = binarySearch(num, arr, SIZE);
      cout << "Sequential Search comparisons: " << pos + NUM_FOR_CAL1<< endl;
      cout << "The position of the number is " << pos + NUM_FOR_CAL1 << endl;
      if(pos != -NUM_FOR_CAL1) total++;
      cout << "Binary Search comparisons: " << total << endl;
      cout << "The position of the number is " << pos + NUM_FOR_CAL1 << endl;
      cout << "Do you want to search again (Y = Yes) : ";
      YesNo = NUM_FOR_CAL2;
      cin >> YesNo;
   }//end of do while loop to search for array and display comparisons
    while(YesNo == 'Y' || YesNo == 'y');

   system("Pause");
   return 0;
}//end main

//searching array using binarySearch
int binarySearch(int t, int arr[], int n)

{
   for(int i = ZERO_FOR_CAL; i < n; ++i)
     if(arr[i] == t) return i;
   return -NUM_FOR_CAL1;
}//end of binarySearch

//searching array using bubbleSort
int bubbleSort(int num[], int n)
{
int i, j, flag = NUM_FOR_CAL1;
int temp, swap = ZERO_FOR_CAL;

for(i = NUM_FOR_CAL1; (i <= n) && flag; i++)
{
    flag = NUM_FOR_CAL2;
    for (j = NUM_FOR_CAL2; j < (n-NUM_FOR_CAL1); j++)
    {
        if (num[j+NUM_FOR_CAL1] < num[j])
        {
            temp = num[j];
            num[j] = num[j+NUM_FOR_CAL1];
            num[j+NUM_FOR_CAL1] = temp;
            flag = NUM_FOR_CAL1;
            swap++;
        }//end of if statement
    }//end of for loop
}//end of for loop
return swap;
}//end bubbleSort

void printArray(int arr[], int SIZE)
{

   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      cout << arr[i];
      if(i < SIZE - 1) cout << ", ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you write code, it is very important to develop new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible. In this case, you should get the bubble sort working perfectly (using `printArray()` for diagnostics) before attempting to hook it into a larger program that does things like searches and user I/O.

Comment: Haha thanks. However, I'm not too sure how to fix the bubbleSort function.

@Beta

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to a simple and common error unrelated to the question title. This question is unlikely to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: _"I finished my code recently, but my output for my bubbleSort function is wrong."_ Then in what way is it finished?

Comment: Code wise unless there's something that needs to be fixed not related to the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Your `j` loop:

```
for (j = NUM_FOR_CAL2; ... )
```

starts at j=2, so it simply never looks at the first two elements of the array.

A good way to detect this problem is by starting with a smaller array and using diagnostic output statements like:

```
cout << "now comparing " << num[j+1] << " to " << num[j] << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks Beta! Also, you can move it to off topic if you don't find it useful. I'll try to be better in the future.

Does everything else seem okay? 

@Beta